# Building android project with pure Intelij toling, without gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup Intelij to build simple Android project without the Gradle.

I know it is possible, as I was using it before.

I'm setting up the project `foo` out of the existing structure:

```
foo/
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── res
│   ├── drawable
│   │   ├── icon_background.xml
│   │   ├── icon_foreground.xml
│   │   └── icon.xml
│   └── values
│       ├── colors.xml
│       └── strings.xml
└── src
    └── foo
        └── Main.java
```

Android module is detected correctly and configured. SDK is there, folders are marked correctly and structure recognized. But it seems that when build icon is clicked, no android specific builders are triggered. R.java and Manifest.java are not generated same as the apk file.

I wonder if it is some bug in the recent version, or i forgot to configure something.

**What should I set up to make idea to build properly my app.**

*In case of any more details needed please ask in the comments, I will update the question.*

Comment: `I was using it before.` What IDE and IDE version did you use? The Android projects are only supported by Gradle build for a very long time. Non-Gradle support is no longer provided and not longer maintained. I advise you to use Gradle-based Android project. It You will benefit from it in the long run anyway.

Comment: @Andrey according to the commits history it was approx 2 years ago :D Damn, that time. I would preffer to avoid gradle at any cost as I literly hate it for the magic it is doing in the bckground without any serious documentation. Non gradle support is provided, and cand be configured. it simply does not work for some reason. They also introduced non gradle for java and kotlin projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation from the JetBrains support that non-Gradle build is not more supported for the Android projects. Sadly...